# Getting [Errno 2] No such file or directory: whenever the filename is changed in Python script

Tags: python

I am running Python35 in windows 8.

I have a python script that obtains exif metadata from typical jpg image files. It is seen to 'work', but runs into a 'no such file or directory problem' whenever I type a new filename into the script.

For example - I place two images 182830.jpg and 182833.jpg into my directory C:\Python35\Scripts

My python script (which I grabbed from stack-exchange and tinkered with to make it work - shown below) is also placed in the same directory, and this script will actually run properly from the IDLE editor for Python35. Or at least, the script will run when first applied to the image file '182830.jpg'

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

# path to the image or video
imagename = "182830.jpg"

# read the image data using PIL
image = Image.open(imagename)

# extract EXIF data
exifdata = image._getexif()

# iterating over all EXIF data fields
for tag_id in exifdata:
    # get the tag name, instead of human unreadable tag id
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
    data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
    # decode bytes 
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        data = data.decode()
    #print("{tag:30}: {data}")
    print(tag, data)
image.close()
```

What currently has me stumped and baffled is that - the script will work/run nicely for that file (ie. '182830.jpg'), and the script will keep running nicely if I repeatedly click on 'Run' (in the IDLE editor).

But when I **manually type** in a different filename, such as 18283**3**.jpg, then I get an error message that says [FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '182833.jpg'].

However, very interestingly (and repeatably) - the script will work/run just fine (always) if I go to the directory C:\Python35\Scripts and I physically use the mouse to copy the **name** of the file (not copy the file itself!) and then paste that copied filename into the script.

Also - very interestingly, if I rename both image files to 'pic1.jpg' and 'pic2.jpg', then (interestingly) the script has absolutely no running issues if I simply edit the script by manually changing the '1' (in pic1.jpg) to a '2' ... and vice versa.

Any help toward my understanding of this 'no such file or directory' issue will be fantastic.

I am finding that the issue never occurs if I grab (eg. copy file**name**) the filename from the directory (and paste that name into my script!). I find that manually editing (by typing) the filename in the script leads to this 'no such file' issue. Thanks in advance all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You glance over the fact you're running this script from IDLE, but that may be part of the problem.

It honestly sounds like a working directory problem or similar; also, you really shouldn't place your own code (much less data such as images) within `C:\Python35\Scripts`; that's mostly managed by `pip` and other Python tools.

So, assuming you move your script to, say, `C:\KennysExifProgram\program.py`, along with the files, so you have

```
C:\KennysExifProgram\program.py
C:\KennysExifProgram\182830.jpg
C:\KennysExifProgram\182833.jpg
```

we can edit the program to run through all JPEGs in that directory, with the kicker being we use the absolute path to the directory we know those files are in:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import glob
import os


def show_image_exif(imagename):
    # read the image data using PIL
    image = Image.open(imagename)

    # extract EXIF data
    exifdata = image._getexif()

    # iterating over all EXIF data fields
    for tag_id in exifdata:
        # get the tag name, instead of human unreadable tag id
        tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
        data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
        # decode bytes
        if isinstance(data, bytes):
            data = data.decode()
        # print("{tag:30}: {data}")
        print(tag, data)


image_directory = r"C:\KennysExifProgram"

# Figure out a list of all images
all_images = glob.glob(os.path.join(image_directory, "*.jpg"))

# Loop over them
for image in sorted(all_images):
    print(image)
    show_image_exif(image)
    print("========")
```

That should work out better for you! :)

(You can also use `image_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)` to have the program default to the directory where it itself is located.)

Comment: Thanks so much AKX! I will be testing that today. Thanks genuinely for your time and help! I will test that (following your recommendations and help) and will certainly report back here! Very much appreciated!

Comment: AKX!! Massively embarrassing here! Massively. I assumed that the two image files had pretty much the same number, except for the last digit! I shot myself in the foot here. Massive apologies from me. That was poor and inexcusable attention to detail. I'm glad I asked a question in other ways, as the recommendations and advice (and other code) is going to help me more than a lot. Thanks for going out of your way to help AKX. I'll show what you showed me to others! Also learned a big lesson (or reminder) in attention to detail. Thanks again AKX!

Comment: AKX - just to clarify - the two files (as I genuinely see them here) turned out to be 183330.jpg and 182833.jpg. What threw me off (but no excuse for it) was that these two files were longer before, such as 20200707_183330.jpg and 20200707_182833.jpg. Being not observant enough, I thought the two numbers after the underscore were almost the same. That was a really bad mistake. Just admitting my blunder here (tunnel vision - not good!).

Comment: AKX ----- just reporting back again. Your code that you added on is incredible! It works excellently. I'm going to go through all of it, to really learn from your example. You showed and taught me a lot with just this code here. Thanks very much again!